# Javascript code to fade the output after 1 second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to display the dimensions of the window and finally I was able to do it:

All i want now is to fade the output text after one second after the resize happened; is this possible?

```
$(window).on('resize', showSize);
showSize();
function showSize() {
    $('#size').html($(window).height() + 'px x ' + $(window).width() + 'px');
```

}

Comment: You are right; fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $(window).on('resize', showSize);
  showSize();
  function showSize() {
    $('#size').show(); // show
    $('#size').html($(window).height() + 'px x ' + $(window).width() + 'px');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#size').fadeOut(); // hide after 1 second
    }, 1000);
  }
```

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r1vmjxx9/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(window).on('resize', showSize);
showSize();
function showSize() {
$('#size').html($(window).height() + 'px x ' + $(window).width() + 'px');
setTimeout(function() {
$('#size').fadeOut();
}, 1000 );
}
```

see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r1vmjxx9/2/)

Comment: Your anwer is also right!